# HTML 5 Geo Location Browser prompt

Tags: html, geolocation

I've a very simple HTML 5 app which tries to determine the users's current location.

Per the spec, supported browsers are supposed to show a prompt like this: "{XYZ} Would like to know your current location".

What does it work?
This is working fine if I open a broser window and directly open that page.

What it doesn't work?
However, when I get directed to that page via the  link I don't see the prompt and an empty page. I have to refresh the page to see the browser prompt. I used FireFox 11 and Chrome on my iPhone 4.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any control over this as it's implemented by the browers.

As a side note, the Geolocation API is not part of HTML5, it's a W3C specification.